# How to fix a rattling blower motor

Tags: furnace

Here is [a video](https://youtube.com/shorts/RIznpoeiVhw?feature=share) that shows the noise my blower motor is making. If anyone can identify the noise and tell me if it's a bearing or a loose bolts on the housing that would be great before I tear into it.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to check for loose bolts, no?

Comment: I predict a trip to Grainger in your future.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an impeller out of balance.  Why is unknown and will require your inspection. It could be rust, dirt and dust, pet hair, physical damage or another reason and be coupled with loose mounting from the shaking and possible worn bearings. The entire assembly needs to be inspected. It won't sound like that if only a bolt or 2 is loose.
The good news is you can change the impeller if needed and Keep the motor if the bearings are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get to the blower and inspect it to see if the wheel is out of balance, if the wheel has debris in it, whether the bearings are bad or loose, or if the mount for the motor is loose. We can not determine the problem by just hearing the noise it is making. You have to get to the blower and determine what is wrong or call in a professional.